# WebRequest - Prevent redirection

Tags: c#, redirect, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse, http-status-code-302

I am using a `WebRequest` to read an HTML site. The server seems to be redirecting my request.

My Code is similar to the following:

```
    String URI = "http://www.foo.com/bar/index.html"
    WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(URI);
    WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
    String returnedContent = sr.ReadToEnd();
```

When I check the content of the `returnedContent` it contains the content from a redirection like "http://www.foo.com/FOO_BAR/index.html". I am sure my requested URL exists since it is part of the recieved response (as an IFrame).

Is there a way to prevent the `WebResponse` to be redirected and get the content of the requested url?

**UPDATE**

Setting `req.AllowAutoRedirect = false` leads to a `302 Found` state code, but does not deliver the acutal content.

Some more details:
My requested url was `http://www.foo.com/bar/index.html` the content I receive is located in `http://www.foo.com/FOO_BAR/index.html`

The response looks similar to this:

```
<body>
    <div>
        <iframe src="/foo/index.html"></iframe>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.allowautoredirect.aspx

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `HttpWebRequest`’s [`AllowAutoRedirect` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.allowautoredirect.aspx):

```
…
var req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URI);
req.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
…
```

Comment: I am getting a "302 Found" Repsonse code instead of the content - any Idea?

Comment: @Jaster: Yes, that's the redirect code. If you don't want to be redirected to the content, then where *do* you expect to find the content? Are you sure the URL in the `<iframe>` is right? If so, you might need to fake a header. Try `Referer`. If that one doesn't work, there's another one, let me find it...

Comment: Could you be so kind a provide a sample on how to use a Referer?

Comment: @Jaster: `req.Referer = "<insert referring URL>";`. The referring URL should be the one to which you get redirected by default.

Comment: Referer did the job. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a rather old post, but thought I'd share what I found in my particular situation...

I was trying to access a site to see if specific content is available. I found that it kept redirecting away from the site I requested to a local version of the site. I noticed some cookies that were responsible for the redirect. If anyone else runs into the same issue, it's possible that there's a cookie or some other request header that you can play with to prevent the redirect away from your intended target.

In my case all I had to do was something like this:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
//whatever other headers you need...
request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, "ipRedirectOverride=true");
```

Note that this is just an example, your cookie name / value may be different