# C# Httpwebrequest manual redirect

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

Occasionally upon sending requests to a link, it automatically redirects me to an unwanted page, so to prevent this I've tried creating an if statement for redirecting, however I'm struggling with multiple issues.

Code examples:

Sending the request -

```
string requestUriString = "https://example.com/page1";
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestUriString);
```

Getting response -

```
        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            using (Stream stream2 = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream2, Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                    str6 = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
            return str6;
        }
```

The function

```
 return str6;
```

returns page contents to the original application to be processed.

However  I want to implement an if statement for page redirects, what I've tried is to do -

```
        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            using (Stream stream2 = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                if ((int)response.StatusCode >= 300 && (int)response.StatusCode <= 399)
                {   
                    string newurl = "https://www.example.com/page2";

                    request = request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(newurl);

                }
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream2, Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                    str6 = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
            return str6;
        }
```

But it doesn't seem to work, as after

```
if ((int)response.StatusCode >= 300 && (int)response.StatusCode <= 399)
```

I need it to continue with the initial process which is

```
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream2, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                str6 = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14012384/webrequest-prevent-redirection) might help, although I guess it doesn't answer your question in full.